# Windows 10 IIS XMLHTTPREQUEST.SEND() problem

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, xmlhttprequest

Recently I've set myself a simple CRUD project where I emulate a database table using an array of javascript objects.

This all worked fine which led me to evolve the project into getting and setting data via a ColdFusion API.

I then push data into the array (from a database) using a getData method (and a "get" request in the xml.open() method.) This worked so well that I felt like a boss... until I started implementing the setData method...

Using a "post" request, I simply intend to send the array (which looks like this: [{firstname: val1, lastname:val2}]) to a ColdFusion API.

The problem is, if I set the header as "application/json", it sends a totally empty structure! So I fixed this by setting the request header as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and this now does post a string which contains the data, however this brings me to the final problem.

I stringify the object and doing a console.log() check shows the data looks good and ready to go. But when the data arrives at the server it looks like my array object is being set as the structure key, and the structure value is totally blank. See below:

[screenshot of the mutated(?) data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozO1N.png)

According to my google searches, all I'm supposed to do is stringify the client, and then deserializeJSON the arriving packet.... but for some reason the string above is produced which then errors the app.

Any ideas on what the problem could be? Is there a setting in IIS? I should further add that I am sending my requests to a dev site which is setup on the same machine, and the client is a html file.

EDIT

Follows is the sample javascript code:

```
var URL = "http://dev.thepeoplesite.com/api/Person.cfc?method=setPerson&returnformat=json";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(p.persondata));
```

Comment: I wasnt sure I needed to include code as its pretty straight forward. All I am doing is the following: data[{firstname:"john",lastname:"smith"},{firstname: "hello", lastname:"world"}].

I then pass the data like follows xmlhttprequest.send(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Ok I have now added the setData client code. I would be very surprised if this were a code issue, strikes me as more a server/header issue probably

Comment: Please elaborate on `errors the app`.

Comment: I would have thought that would be obvious... can you not see the screen shot? Im passing a incorrectly formed json string to the coldfusion api, thus deserializeJSON errors as it cannot find the key/value pair... if you look at the screen shot you will get the problem. And there is no way my code is wrong as the client is as posted above... nothing more to it! IMO its something to do with lucee and the IIS on my local dev, just want to know if anyone has experienced this and could give me the solution